I don't have data from my sqlite3 when run pytest
When I run my test with pytest, the sqlite dbb is empty, the sqlite file is of course not, I certainly make a mistake but I don't know where:
pytest.ini
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = drf.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py

test_factory_boy.py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_share_link():
    share_link = ShareLinksFactory.create()

    assert share_link.id is not None
    assert share_link.limit_datetime == timezone.now() + timedelta(days=30)

    assert share_link.web_share_file_folder is not None
    assert share_link.web_share_file_folder.path.startswith('Share/automatic/')

    delete_all_instances_from_factory_boy()

the error
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
    "%s matching query does not exist." %
    self.model._meta.object_name
)
user.models.uuid_cifs_users.UuidCifsUsers.DoesNotExist: UuidCifsUsers matching query does not exist.

The user is called from the factory when a instance is created.
If I check from a python console I have the right data and the user,
when I try to do same in the test with pdb the dbb seems to be empty
I tried modifying the pytest.ini but nothing changes.
